# ng-repeat in table and properties binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` on a list of objects where each object has 5 properties.

The first four properties are a number and the actual values displayed in the table, something like:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="object in objects">

            <td ng-style="{ 'color': 'object.colors['color1']'}" 
                ng-mouseenter="changeColor(object ,'color1',true)" 
                ng-mouseleave="changeColor(object ,'color1',false)" > 
               {{object .property1}}
            </td>
--other three <td> below for properties 2 3 4 in the same way.
```

My Goal is to change color on mouse hover for a specific cell based on the fifth object property which is somenthing like a group of pair {colorname - colorcode}

Example:

`Object1.property5= [{'color1'='red'},{'color2' = 'green'}` etc..

The function `changeColor` takes three parameters:

- the object to operate on
- the name of the color
- a boolean simply to restore the color when the mouse is moved away from the cell.

  ```
  function changeColor( object, colorLabel, isOver ) {
      if (isOver) {
          object.property5[colorLabel] = '#00afec';
      } else {
          object.property5[colorLabel] = 'black';
      }
  }
  ```

Now, if we look at the example in the beginning, moving the mouse over the objects triggers the `changeColor` for that object. It correctly changes the `color1` property value to `#00afec`, but looks like some binding is missing and the `ng-style` does not detect that change in the nested property.

How can i fix this? I also have a feeling that this is not the optimal solution so any other suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: To update 1st  -to 4th element color :
 function changeColor( object, colorLabel, isOver ) {
            if (isOver) {
              object.colors[colorLabel] = object.property5[colorLabel]
            } else {
                object.colors[colorLabel]  = 'black';
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i opted however to use a css. I don't know why i didn't think about it before. Anyway, for the original solution the problem was that in the ng-style i put object.colors['color1'] between ''. That was the issue.